# How to write a cron schedule for US Market Hours

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-cloudwatch

I am looking to schedule a Lambda function on AWS using CloudWatch to trigger every minute during US market hours (9:30am - 4pm EDT).

I believe the only way to do this is using cron, and I'm not extremely familiar with cron and its different flavours (AWS seems to allow some non-standard features like `MON-FRI`).

So far, I have worked out that:

`cron(0/1 14-21 ? * MON-FRI *)`

seems to work for 9am-4pm (given I am using a London timezone region, this includes the 5hr time difference).

How do I get this to start at 9:30am EDT? And is there a way for cron to automatically keep up to date with daylight savings time changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get this to start at 8:30am EDT?

It isn't possible using standard cron syntax (including in CloudWatch Events) to express 8:30-4pm.

To work around this limitation, you could have two expressions

```
30-59 14 ? * MON-FRI *
* 15-21 ? * MON-FRI *
```

or you could account for the logic in your code.

> And is there a way for cron to automatically keep up to date with daylight savings time changes?

Cron will use the local system time when determining when to run jobs. E.g. if you use cron on Linux, it will use whatever `/etc/timezone` (debian) says. The time zone files (as [provided by IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones)) have the time change info encoded. With CloudWatch Events, [all times are UTC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html). You'd need to correct for time zone/time change in your code or use cron on an OS with the EST/EDT offset.

Comment: One thing that comes to my mind is that you could have another lambda triggered twice a year to change the original lambda hours to match EST/EDT - that way you can keep your application clean.

Comment: Surprisingly elegant solution to a surprisingly unsolvable problem. Seems kind of obvious when you think about it - although I'm sad to report that daylight-savings time does not seem to be managed that obviously by AWS

Answer (score 0):

You can use CloudWatch Events to trigger the lambda function when desired.

It also supports [scheduled expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) that supports cron syntax and is in UTC timezone.

Comment: Thanks; perhaps my question was unclear - I am asking for the cron statement itself as it seems to require more complexity than the simpler cron tasks I have seen so far.